# What is Cluster in Docker?

Tags: docker, cluster-computing

I am new in Docker. I am trying to understand the cluster in Docker but getting a bit confused.

**Can anyone help me to understand the cluster in Docker in details?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cluster in docker refers to multiple nodes joined using swarm mode. Containers are scheduled across the various nodes, and networking is configured with overlay networking to look similar to bridge networks to the containers, but across multiple nodes.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/

Comment: What is docker cluster in Kubernets? BMitch

Comment: A Kubernetes cluster is similar to swarm mode, but a fair bit more complex and should probably have a Kubernetes expert answering the question.